# HTTP redirection types

Tags: http, redirect, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am new to Web Technology and I'm researching about GET and POST methods and forms of HTTP redirections + HTTP status codes.

I'm aware that there exist two methods of redirection. One in which the server returns the request with a 301/2 status code and responses with the new URL and the other in which the client is not aware of the redirection.

What are these two methods called? Where can I research more about them to be enough to be able to program these two types of redirections?

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Comment: 301/302 is called redirect. The other thing sounds like `url rewriting` or even `proxy server`

Answer (score 1):

There are actually many more ;) you should start by reading **carefully** the related [wikipedia page on url redirection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_redirection).

Comment: i found out that what i was looking for was sendRedirect and forwardRedirect methods of redirection! I just needed to find from where to begin!